# Add a Query parameter in Mule

Tags: http, parameters, header, mule

Hi I want to add a query parameter Age = 23
I tried adding

```
message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.Age = '23'
```

In a expression

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.Age= '23';]]></expression-component>
```

It won't work.

Comment: Is this for an HTTP request or response? You should use a request/response builder if that is the case.

Comment: Please post the flow  that you are using this.

Comment: This is for posting HTTP request

Answer (score 1):

Inbound properties are Immutable hence you must add it in outbound property to add a query param in your outbound http connector you can use the below

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="outway" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="Age" value="23"/>
 </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add properties to an outgoing message they need to be in the outbound scope:

```
message.outboundProperties.'http.query.params'.Age= '23'
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to modify inbound properties but you can´t, they are inmutable

*Properties have two main scopes: inbound and outbound.*

***Inbound properties are immutable***, are automatically generated by the message source and cannot be set or manipulated by the user.  They contain metadata specific to the message source that prevents scrambling of data formats or other processing mishaps later in the message’s lifecycle. A message retains its inbound properties only for the duration of the flow; when a message passes out of a flow, its inbound properties do not follow it (see image below).

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/mule-message-structure

You must add it to outbound as Ryan said.